# Django node.js socket.io

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make a realtime messaging application. There will be 2 distinct server(node.js and django) and when a user sends message to another user message will be stored in database than node.js will send a message to receiver like "You have new Message!". For that i am planing to call url which node.js serve. So node.js and django will interact each other. And what is best way send message to specifig client ? (I keep clients with their id's in a assosicative array.)

what do you think about that? is it efficent or do you suggest better way to do this ?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the node.js server?  Why do you want to take out that functionality from django and put it there?

Comment: Django's nature doesnt support interaction with sockets. I know there is implementation named django-socketio but I am not sure to use it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you're trying to do? Is it a web-based application? If not, why Django? and if it is, what sockets are you referring to?  websockets?

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer Yes, it is a web-based application and i refer to websockets.

Answer (score -1):

Now that I understand more about what you're trying to do, here my answer, just keep in mind that this only reflects my opinion, and I bet that many others would argue about it.

It all matter on how much traffic you expect to have in your application. If it's not a high traffic application, then efficiency in run-time is insignificant when compared to that of the development, and so choose the technology you feel most comfortable with.

If though you do aim for high traffic application, then I believe that this setup is not a good one.
First of all while http based communication between servers might seem comfortable, you are dealing with the overhead of http over tcp (since http is based on tcp). And so regular tcp sockets scale better, but on the other hand if you write the sockets server in python than you can run it from the same process as the django and then just use it as an object from django (you're entering the realm of threads here). But that's problematic if you have a few web instances, again depends on how much traffic you expect.

As for your choice for implementing the messaging server, I've never tested node.js but I believe that in benchmark tests it won't compare for something written in erlang or Java NIO. For example: [JAVA AIO (NIO.2) VS NODEJS](http://www.olympum.com/java/java-aio-vs-nodejs/)